# Add a watcher for form fields

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel Nova, and I want to make "Save" button(on the Update view)  unavailable while all required fields are empty.
Here's the part of the code of the "Update.vue" file that creates my form fields:

```
<div v-for="field in fields">
 <component
    @file-deleted="updateLastRetrievedAtTimestamp"
    :is="'form-' + field.component"
    :errors="validationErrors"
    :resource-id="resourceId"
    :resource-name="resourceName"
    :field="field"
 /></div>
```

`Fields` array fills with the data from backend.

So I can see this structure in the Vue dev tool. And when I change the input value it changes `value` of `<form-text-field>`, but I don't see this changes anywhere in my `Update` component.

[image]

So my question is - How I can get changes of my input fields dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

In Vue data flows only one way, so the change of data in your Update component will be reflected on form-text-field, but not the other way around. To create 2-way data binding you should use v-model.

I suppose form-text-field is one of your custom components, in that case you should create a custom v-model for it. See: [Customizing Component v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model)

If you can't get it work post your implementation of form-text-field here, so we can help.